# Visual Studio Build Tools 14 cannot find stdio.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Ayo,

Now I have attempted other solutions to the problem that over people have had success in. But unfortunately, technology is not on my side today.

As the title says my C++ compiler says it cannot find 'stdio.h' then leaves with error status 3, Here is the stacktrace https://gyazo.com/d26d47054ee30f7e03524b7d8c0052a8

How would I be able to resolve this?

Thanks,
Duke.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1700bbwd.aspx

Comment: Cheers for the link, Neil! I have tried this method but I am still yielding the same results, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat worked for me. See details on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx).

Comment: this solution does not work for Microsoft Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft now implements C run time library as a "Universal CRT", which is part of the OS. And to develop for it, you will need the SDK for the OS, a.k.a. Windows SDK.

[CRT Library Features (Microsoft Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=vs-2019)

However, there's a not-so-obvious component of the SDK installation that will install the minimum needed <strike>SDK</strike>CRT components (ca. 700MB).

It is called, appropriately, **Windows Universal CRT SDK**.

You can select it by installing the [Build Tools component](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#vstool-2019-family), which will in turn install the VS Installer. Then you modify the Build Tools to include the individual SDK component.

[image: Visaul Studio Installer component selection window]

But you won't get far with this, unless you can scam Windows into running an app that doesn't depend on its' kernel, implying you will most likely need the full Windows SDK for the kernel32 library and its' dependencies.